# Can't import shared.SharedService in thrift tutorial

Tags: python, thrift

I seem to be mis-understanding something about Apache Thrift. I have it installed and generated python bindings using the tutorial.thrift file. I manipulated my `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable to allow me to import from the generated files. When I import `tutorial.Calculator' it can't find`shared.SharedService`. Is this a dependency of Apache Thrift or something I have to define?

```
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/tmp$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHON:`pwd`/gen-py
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/tmp$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/ericu/tmp/gen-py
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/tmp$ c
c: command not found
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~/tmp$ cd 
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ pyhon
No command 'pyhon' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
pyhon: command not found
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ python
Python 2.7.5 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (default, Sep 23 2013, 20:17:03) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tutorial
>>> tutorial.Calculator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Calculator'
>>> import tutorial.Calculator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ericu/tmp/gen-py/tutorial/Calculator.py", line 10, in <module>
    import shared.SharedService
ImportError: No module named shared.SharedService
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharedService is part of another Thrift IDL file, which is included into the tutorial.thrift IDL file. Tbus, you have to generate the code for the Shared service as well. The easiest way is to call the Thrift compiler with the `-r` option ("recursive") which will generate code for the passed IDL file and all included dependencies.

The tutorial pages are indeed misleading here. If you want to file a JIRA ticket, please do.

Answer (score -1):

please add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/thrift/master/tutorial/shared.thrift to your thrift directory at first ,then thrift -r -gen

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32314932)